# GWT:how to change row color in GWT Celltable

Tags: gwt

i have a celltable in GWT, I can change color of a specific column by this

```
            celltable.addColumnStyleName(4, "bluetext");
```

but how can i change for example color of row No 3

Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have to provide a `RowStyles` object that returns css class names for each row.  So, to set a particular color for a row, you'd have to define a css class with that color, and then cause your `RowStyles` object to return that class for the relevant rows.

I think you set this with `cellTable.setRowStyles` or something similar.

```
cellTable.setRowStyles(new RowStyles<T>() {
    @Override
    public String getStyleNames(T rowObject, int rowIndex) {
        if (rowIndex == 3) {
            return "bluetext";
        } else {
            return "normaltext";
        } 
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to update row color based on a value changed in one of the cells, you can add the following code to the fieldUpdater of this cell:

```
@Override
public void update(int index, Object object, String value) {
    if (someConditionIsMet) {
        myTable.getRowElement(index).addClassName("redBackground");
    }
}
```

In your CSS file add this style:

```
.redBackground {
    background-color: red !important;
}
```

Comment: the CSS file you mean is your_module.css ?! because it didn't work for me. thanks.

Comment: Whatever CSS file you use for your application. If you have several, they may conflict with each other. You can use browser tools to see which style is actually applied to your table row, and which styles are ignored.

Comment: I do see that the css class is applied to <tr> element but the style is not displayed!

Comment: !important makes selected element not highlighted.

Comment: @SimonLogic: If you apply a color to the entire row, it will override a cell color. If you want to keep the cell color for a selected cell, you can override it in CSS with a more specific selector (e.g. '.redBackground .selected').

Answer (score 2):

To answer the last comment that the style is in the row element but is not being rendered:
Using setRowStyles(new RowStyles() ...
The only way I got the styles to appear was to use brute force.
I had to remove the row from my List store, add it back to the same index and then refresh the RowModel.
For what it's worth.