# How to style a Row of CellTable when user click on a Cell (GWT)?

Tags: gwt

I want that when user click on a Cell belonging to a row of CellTable, then it will style the row.

So I tried:

```
       myColumn.setFieldUpdater(new FieldUpdater<String[], String>(){
            @Override
            public void update(int index, String[] object, String value){
                if(mycondition){
                    myCellTable.getRowElement(index).addClassName(getView().getRes().css().blueText());
                    myCellTable.redraw();
                }

            }
        });
```

As stated in the above code, we can capture the `index` of the row, so row no is not the problem, but why **nothing happened**.

So How to fix it?

Comment: You have asked same question here [How to style the cell that is the intersection of row and column in celltable (GWT)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22602090/how-to-style-the-cell-that-is-the-intersection-of-row-and-column-in-celltable-g/22616248#22616248). Please have a look again. If still there is any issue. Please let me know.

Comment: i need to do it dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not redraw the table after you set a style to the row element. Your style will be lost.

Comment: yes ur answer is right, but why it did not accept some other style like font-weight:normal. Why it accept "background:red" but not accept "font-weight:normal" or "font-color:red"

Comment: myCellTable.getRowElement(index).getStyle().setFontWeight(FontWeight.NORMAL); also doesn't work

Comment: myColumn.setCellStyleNames(getView().getRes().css().myClickableTextCellStyleNormal()); also doesn't work

Comment: i found ur answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9022921/gwthow-to-change-row-color-in-gwt-celltable

Comment: u said "Whatever CSS file you use for your application. If you have several, they may conflict with each other. You can use browser tools to see which style is actually applied to your table row, and which styles are ignored. " so table row don't accept Font-Weight:normal?

Comment: Inspect this element in your browser to see which styles are applied, and which styles are not.

Comment: can u come up other solution like style all the cells in the row?

Comment: finally i fopund a solution that is to remove the object then add it back dataProvider & it works

Comment: It is the same as calling on dataProvider.refresh().